# How to load the loading scene background in cocos2d without blanking out?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I have a `cocos2d` game that has a loading scene where we load a bunch of assets. The game starts with the splash screen, and then launches the loading scene. The loading scene starts by loading the background, so the user sees the loading scene background while the assets are being loaded.

I load the loading scene background by calling `CCSprite::spriteWithFile:` and passing the filepath: `loadingbackground.pvr.ccz`

It seems to work differently on different devices:

1. On iphone (3gs) simulator, I see the loading scene as expected.
2. On iphone retina simulator, I don't see the loading scene (there aren't many assets yet, so may be happening quickly) and it goes directly to the main menu scene.
3. On the ipad 3 device, the splash screen comes up, and then there is a half second of black screen, and then the main menu scene shows up.

I want to see what I can do to avoid that black screen showing up on iPad 3. I suspect this is because of the time taken to load the loading background.

I have tried the following optimizations (mostly based on @Steffen's [blog post on memory optimization](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/)):

1. Moved the loading background (originally 2.3 MB RGB8 png file) into a pvr.ccz spritesheet by itself, which reduced its size to 1.8 MB.
2. Removed the image from the texture soon after use.

I still see a black screen on iPad 3. Any suggestions?

Update: Found the issue - I had some code where I was overriding `OnEnter` and calling `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene]` in it, and also calling the same from the background thread. Removed the OnEnter overload and it worked without flicker.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore whatever happens in Simulator. That's not relevant, focus on the device.

When the loading scene initializes and you add the loading scene's background, make sure you schedule update and load your assets in the update method. Otherwise if you load the assets in init, the background won't be drawn because you're loading all the assets before cocos2d gets to redraw the screen.

If this still fails, simply send the visit message to the background sprite followed by [[CCDirector sharedDirector] drawScene]. This forces a redraw of the scene.

Comment: I did have assets loading in the background, so marking as answer. Also fixed another bug which I have described in an update to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this cocos2d-iphone or cocos2d-x ? make sure the tags are correct :)

I think you're referring to the startup flicker, there are a few ways to avoid that.
first thing you need to make sure you're handling the rootViewController correctly for iOS 6 and iOS 5 and below, there are a little changes for each.

You can find a little reference here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/34471

Second thing you need to know that simulator's behaviour is not stable, you should always rely on real devices for testing, but it's very likely you'll still have the flicker issues.

Sorry I didn't provide example code, but you haven't supported enough information to know what's the real issue here.